# Use LINQ to aggregate on a list of lists

Tags: c#, linq

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
public enum Error
{
  Error1,
  Error2,
  Error3,
}

public class DataUnit
{
  public int Data; // Any Data
  public List<Error> Errors { get; private set; }
}

List<DataUnit> DataList;
```

I would like to use LINQ to flatten `DataList` and get the total count of `Error1`, `Error2`, and `Error3`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
dataList
.SelectMany(x => x.Errors)
.GroupBy(x => x)
.Select(g => new { Value = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
```

Comment: Thank you. I also worked out the query-equivalent and adding it here for completeness:
`from x in DataList`
`from y in x.Errors`
`group y by y into g`
`select new { Value = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq's selectMany() statement for that:

```
DataList.SelectMany(list => list.Errors).Where(error => error == Error.Error1).Count()
```